# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-express

I want to plot plotly express grouped bar chart to show no of births in each decade just [like this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnEpf.png).

```
pivot_dayofweek=final.pivot_table(values='births',index='dayofweek',columns='decade',aggfunc='mean')    



pivot_dayofweek=pivot_dayofweek.loc[['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']]
pivot_dayofweek
```

[pivot_dayofweek dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMktp.png)

```
px.bar(pivot_dayofweek,x=pivot_dayofweek.index,y=pivot_dayofweek.values,barmode='group')
```

but when I run the above code it gives me an error [Click to show the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwZWB.png)

Answer (score 0):

- have simulated data set and pivot table
- simplest way is to restructure pivot dataframe to be ready for **plotly**

  1. `stack()` *decade* columns into index
  2. `reset_index()` to make index columns
  3. make *decade* a string to prevent it being treated as continuous

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("1-jan-1960", "31-dec-1989", freq="D")}).pipe(
    lambda d: d.assign(
        births=np.random.uniform(1, 5, len(d)),
        dayofweek=d["date"].dt.strftime("%A"),
        decade=d["date"].dt.year - d["date"].dt.year % 10,
    )
)

dfp = df.pivot_table(
    values="births", index="dayofweek", columns="decade", aggfunc="sum"
)

px.bar(
    dfp.stack().reset_index().assign(decade=lambda d: d["decade"].astype(str)),
    color="decade",
    x="dayofweek",
    y=0,
    barmode="group",
).update_layout(title="No of birth in day in every decade", yaxis={"title":"Births"})
```

[image]